# Error on installing ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

```
[root@arch ~]# rvm install 1.8.7
```

-->

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 - #fetching 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p334 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p334
ERROR: Error running 'bunzip2 < '/usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_6986', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p334/extract.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to extract the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

-->

```
[root@arch ~]# cat /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p334/extract.log
```

-->

```
[2011-04-27 13:47:58] bunzip2 < '/usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_6726
tar: --no-same-owner: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[2011-04-27 13:48:12] bunzip2 < '/usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_6835
tar: --no-same-owner: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[2011-04-27 13:48:22] bunzip2 < '/usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_6910
tar: --no-same-owner: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

If I try to launch

```
bunzip2 < '/usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_6726
```

I get the same error.

But if I remove '--no-same-owner' the promlem dissapeared.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: And, it's still a problem … 3 years later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is bug in rvm, see latest commit https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/52018750763d5321b7b993e201c8589b98e090f9

Comment: `rvm get head && rvm-smile`

Comment: Thanks "rvm get head && rvm get stable && rvm install 1.9.3" worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
rvm get head && rvm get stable && rvm install 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I install under no-root account and the problem disapeared.

Comment: @fl00r: Maybe mean "meme" not "mean"?

Comment: I never used sudo and still have the problem. What solved for you @Demas?