# Unable to install rubygems through rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I'm a noob in ruby and i'm trying to setup Ruby on Rails on ubuntu 12.04. I'm following steps as given in this site https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

But whenever i try to run this command > **rvm rubygems current** i get an error

> "Retrieving rubygems- There is no checksum for
>   'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-.tgz' or
>   'rubygems-.tgz', it's not possible to validate it. If you wish to
>   continue with unverified download add '--verify-downloads 1' after the
>   command."

Any help on this on how to proceed.

Comment: Does it work if you specify a version? E.G. `rvm rubygems 1.5.2`

Comment: isn't rubygems bundled with your ruby?

Comment: @three, rvm handles rubygems installation separately from ruby itself.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? If so accept an answer or add your own and accept that :)

Answer (score 16):

It looks like a bug, but it most likely is fixed already as I can not reproduce it, update RVM and try again:

```
rvm get stable
rvm rubygems current
```

Comment: This did not work for me, as it tried once again to install rubygems 1.8.25, whose tar archive seems to be broken.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem and running `rvm rubygems current` get the similar error. It was trying to install version 1.8.25. I went to [Rubygems website](http://rubygems.org/) and saw the latest version there was 1.8.24. So I ran `rvm rubygems 1.8.24` and it solve the issue, I can install other rubies with RVM normally. Hope that helps

Comment: that's a rubygems release process error, they tag the version but do not release it - it gets fixed in most cases bellow a day, also the fix is not related to the initial question as it was a bug in RVM which was already fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you could use inline RubyGems version (1.8.23 or 1.8.24) define:

```
rvm_rubygems_version=1.8.24 rvm install ruby
```

Or also with specific Ruby version:

```
rvm_rubygems_version=1.8.24 rvm install ruby 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue, but I figured out that combining steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804428/error-on-installing-ruby-with-rvm) and [here](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rvm/) that you can fix the install.

Here are the steps in the order that I completed them and got a clean install:

```
rvm remove ruby
rvm implode
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
rvm reload
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm get head && rvm-smile
rvm rubygems latest
```

`rvm install 1.9.3` will fail at the gems install again, but continue on with the next step, and it will be ok.

Run `gems list` to see that the install worked, and if you'd like to be extra sure, go ahead and install another specific gem and then run `gems list` again.

Answer (score 0):

As [rvm.io](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) website suggests, I installed the rvm using:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

and got the same error as described in the question. I then re-ran:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

and the problem gone and installation finished successfully. 
So not sure what caused this, I suggest to re-try the install command.